# How was time defined before we knew the speed of light was constant or in classical physics?

Tags: speed-of-light, classical-mechanics, time

Nowadays, we now about $c$ the universal speed of light. This lets us define the notion of distance in terms of time (despite the fact that it works the opposite way for our common units.) Before this, how was time defined? Namely, if I said that two events had the same duration, what would I be saying?

Note: I am also asking in relation to classical physics. Namely, if I say that two events will have the same duration (based on Newtonian mechanics, for example), what am I saying?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_timekeeping_devices

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how people chose to define time in the past.  As such it's a question about history and the development of science, measurement, and rigor, rather than physics.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horology

Comment: @BrandonEnright I added a clarifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is what an ideal clock measures. So what's an ideal clock? It's something that measures time.

In other words, physicists don't quite know what time is.

That's okay. They don't quite know what space is, either. What they do know, and know very, very well, is how to measure both, and how the two (time and space) relate to one another. That the speed of light is the same to all observers means that measurements of duration and distance are now known to be observer-dependent. That's a different question, however. I'm going to ignore relativistic effects in this answer.

The current best guess as to what constitutes an ideal clock is the period of the radiation "corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom (at zero Kelvin)." The first part of the quote is from the 1967 definition of the second. The parenthetical remark about temperature is a clarification made thirty years later.

From 1901 to 1967, the best definition of time was the length of an Earth year. Informally, the use of the year as the best clock available goes back to the early 1700s. Before that, the rotation of the Earth was deemed to be the best clock. Halley was the first to realize that rotation of the Earth is an imperfect clock. The Earth's rotation rate is very gradually slowing down, thanks largely to the tides exerted by the Moon.

The rotation of the Earth itself has two somewhat inconsistent rates, the rotation rate with respect to the Sun (what an ideal sundial measures) versus the rotation rate with respect to the stars (what an ideal clock measures). The time-varying difference between these two rates is the "equation of time". This was known to some extent by the ancients. Kepler was the first to argue that the rate with respect to the stars was the correct measure of time. Others (including Halley and Newton) picked up Kepler's cause, but it wasn't until the early 1800s that the civil world switched from time as measured by the Sun to time as measured by the stars as the being the better measure of time.

Answer (score -3):

Being able to sense phenomenon and being able to explain them are different animals.

Consider how many millions of magnetic coils we employ in our daily lives. "Science" still cannot give a single, congruent, fully observable at every level, without referring to other phenomenon, explanation of WHY they work. Obviously they do, and we have figured out that if you put XXX into one, YYY will come out. Over time, the complexity of XXX in and YYY out increases.

Back on topic, "in the beginning", there was no Rolex, only the sun and moon and stars. After living for a day or two, we realized that the sun and moon come around every..... lets call it... a "day". We don't know why, but it seems to do so, without fail. Then we figure out that if you jab a stick into the ground vertically and watch it's shadow, you can measure..... let's call it "time". Some schmuck back then, chose 24 for the number of.... "hours" (why not) in a "day", drew a circle around the stick, and cut it into 24 slices. Since then, Rolex and others began making wrist-mounted sticks that work independent of their physical orientation or geographic location.

Lastly, consider the semi-deprecated measure of time, the "fortnight", which equals 14 suns and/or moons. We defined a convenient, linear, coordinate system for time relative to our own perspective. Time itself may or may not be linear, but we can reliably measure it as such, from our perspective, because our existence is linear. Think of what an Earth-hour would mean to someone living on Titan.

Edit: Also consider that we have "leap-years" to correct (ancient) bad math. Someone, a long time ago, didn't carry a 1.

Edit 2: At the risk of starting a fire, consider that people living approximately 2015 years ago had been keeping track of the year, themselves, for many thousands of years, until someone came along and caused time to "reset" to year 1.

Comment: Year 1 wasn't established until the 6th century by Dionysius Exiguus.  There was no year 0.

Comment: Leap years are not a consequence of bad math.  They are due to the fact that the Earth does not execute an integer number of rotations per revolution about the sun.

Comment: "The exact length of a solar year is actually 11 minutes and 14 seconds less than 365 ¼ days. That means that even if you add a leap day every four years, the calendar would still overshoot the solar year by a little bit—11 minutes and 14 seconds per year."  

When the "year" was invented, someone rounded. They were already wrong then; they didn't become wrong later when we could more accurately measure it.

Comment: If you and I agree to meet in "3 flurbs", will you be late?
If we all experience the flow of time the same, then we just have to agree on how long a "flurb" is. Do we want a flurb to equal 1.0000000 revolutions or 1.000000001 revolutions? The Earth orbits at the same speed, regardless.